# Excel VBA Documents.Open open another empty Word document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, userform

I use an Excel UserForm and VBA to try to open a Word document from a ListBox selection. It opens the desired Word document but it also opens an empty document.

Instead of creating a new Word object each time, I try to use the original Word object

```
  On Error Resume Next
  Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
  If Err.Number > 0 Then Set wdApp = New Word.Application
  On Error GoTo 0
```

However, it always opens two Word documents (one is empty). It will work (only open the desired one) if I create a new Word instance every time, which I don't want.

```
Set wdApp = New Word.Application
```

Any opinions or help will be great appreciated! Thanks!

I tried to use two ways to create Word instance. I hope I can open only desired Word document without creating a new Word instance every time.

1. Open two Word documents, one is empty, undesired

```
  On Error Resume Next
  Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
  If Err.Number > 0 Then Set wdApp = New Word.Application
  On Error GoTo 0
```

2. Open only desired Word document, but I hope I can only use one Word instance, not create new one every time

```
Set wdApp = New Word.Application
```

The whole function is here

```
Sub OpenWord()
  If Not Initialized Then Initialize
   
  'Get or Create a Word Instance
  On Error Resume Next
  Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
  If Err.Number > 0 Then Set wdApp = New Word.Application
  On Error GoTo 0
  
  'Set wdApp = New Word.Application
  
  Dim rows() As String
  Dim row As Variant
  Dim Path As String
  Dim current_folder As String
  Dim temp_folder As String
  Dim cur_file_name As String
  Dim current_time As String
  Dim pdf_path As String
  Dim fso As FileSystemObject
  Set fso = New FileSystemObject
  Dim docWord As Word.Document
  Dim wdDocTgt As Word.Document
  Set wdDocTgt = wdApp.Documents.Add
  
  
  current_folder = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
  
  rows = Split(Sheet2.Range("V6"))

  For Each row In rows
    row = CInt(row)
    Dim FileName, FullFileName As String
    cur_file_name = Sheet3.Cells(row, 5)
    cur_file_name = fso.GetBaseName(cur_file_name)
    Path = current_folder & "/EXPERTSHEETS" & "/" & Sheet3.Cells(row, 14) & "/" & Sheet3.Cells(row, 5) & ".docx"
    If indexsheet.cmdCheckBoxSingle.Value = False Then
        Set docWord = wdApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=Path, ReadOnly:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False)
        docWord.Application.Visible = True
    Else
        With wdDocTgt.Bookmarks("\StartOfDoc").Range
            .InsertFile FileName:=Path, _
                ConfirmConversions:=False, Link:=False, Attachment:=False
            .InsertBreak Type:=2    ' wdSectionBreakNextPage = 2
        End With
    End If
  Next row
  
  'wdApp.Visible = True
  If indexsheet.cmdCheckBoxSingle.Value = True Then
    wdDocTgt.Characters(1).Delete
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: With Word open, and without any error handling, what happens when you run `Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")` ?

Comment: @TimWilliams If I do not open any Word document but only open the Word application (only show the welcome page), the Word application will open my desired Word document without any extra. But if I open a random document, it will open my desired and empty documents.

Comment: You don't show any other code, but it seems there's no issue attaching to an open Word instance, likely the issue is not with what you posted, but with something else we can't see.

Comment: @TimWilliams Hi Tim, I have attached the whole function call. My guess is that Word by default will hide somewhere to open another Word document. After I reveal it, the hidden one will show up.

Comment: That's what I was going to suggest was going on - you might have one or more hidden Word instances running, and GetObject is attaching to one of those and not the visible Word instance...   If you use task Manager to close all "extra" Word instances and make sure there's only a single visible instance open, do you still see the same issue?

Comment: @TimWilliams If I close all the Word documents, it won't. But if I leave one document, it will open two.

Comment: @TimWilliams the basic logic is, that if I create a new Word instance every time, it won't open me two. If I use the current Word instance, it will open two

Answer (score 0):

Please visit the following folder and clear the contents in the folder.

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP
```

You might want to take a backup of that folder before clearing it.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your input Alok, but I don't have anything in that folder. It is empty.

Comment: Can you try removing the error handlers from the code and rerun and share what difference you observe when you run the code. If errors come up, can you share error descriptions or screen shots.

Comment: Also check if you have any code written in Normal.dotm file.

Comment: I did not even touch it

Comment: I did not get any error. It just grabs the current Word instance if it exists. So the basic observation is if I create a new Word instance every time, it will only open a single Word document for me. If I use the current Word instance to open, it will open an extra empty Word document.

Comment: @MichaelChen I've tested your code, before the line `current_folder = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path` but it won't open an extra empty Word document. The line above this `Set wdDocTgt = wdApp.Documents.Add` indeed open a new document however, it will be referred after in the block `With wdDocTgt.Bookmarks("\StartOfDoc").Range`. ……

Comment: @OscarSun you are a genius! Yes, after I put Set wdDocTgt = wdApp.Documents.Add into block it won't open an empty document anymore!! Could you answer it outside I will accept your answer. You definitely solved my confusing.